# Use default language of addressbook on iPhone

Tags: ios

I am using the `peoplePickerNavigationController` to make people browsing the address book of the iPhone and get a contact number.

But with my french iPhone, when i use that, it shows me menus like 'All contacts' or 'home' in english.

How can I tell the `peoplePickerNavigationController` to use the default language of the iPhone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sound like your app doesn't know how to speak French.  You will need to set [CFBundleLocalizations](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html) in info.plist.  Right now, the default language is English.  If you set English and French, `peoplePickerNavigationController` will display the correct language based on the phone Settings --> General --> International --> Language.

Comment: really tricky as i was not able to add them through xcode but only by editing the plist manually .. thanks !